# Using Case in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I want my query to fill in information where results are null. Particularly I want `PlanFirmSpecCode.SpecialCode = FinancialPlanner.LastName` when the special code field is `NULL`. And when my `DirectValue` is `NULL` I want it to display 0.

I'm running into to syntax errors when trying to write the case. How should this be done in the following query:

```
SELECT     Household.Name, FinancialPlanner.LastName, PlanFirmSpecCode.SpecialCode, 
           SUM(Asset.Value) AS HHValue,
           SUM(CASE WHEN financialinst.name = 'National Financial Services' THEN Asset.Value ELSE 0 END) AS NationalValue, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN financialinst.name <> 'National Financial Services'THEN Asset.Value END) AS DirectValue
FROM       PlanFirmSpecCode INNER JOIN
           FinPlanSpecCode ON PlanFirmSpecCode.PlanFirmSpecCodeID = FinPlanSpecCode.PlanFirmSpecCodeID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
           Household INNER JOIN
           Account ON Household.HouseholdID = Account.HouseholdID INNER JOIN
           Asset ON Account.AccountID = Asset.AccountID INNER JOIN
           FinancialPlanner ON Household.FinancialPlannerID = FinancialPlanner.FinancialPlannerID LEFT OUTER JOIN
           FinancialInst ON Account.FinancialInstID = FinancialInst.FinancialInstID ON FinPlanSpecCode.FinancialPlannerID = FinancialPlanner.FinancialPlannerID
WHERE      (Account.Closed <> 'Y') AND (Asset.Value > '0') and (Account.Managed <> 'N')
GROUP BY   Household.Name, FinancialPlanner.LastName, PlanFirmSpecCode.SpecialCode
Order by   household.Name
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Whatever is in the SELECT that is not an aggregate function or literal value needs to be in the GROUP BY statement.
2. Using the `ELSE 0` in the `[DirectValue]` CASE statement, just like it was already in the `[NationalValue]` CASE statement, should do the trick.

Try this:

```
SELECT     Household.Name,
           FinancialPlanner.LastName,
           COALESCE(PlanFirmSpecCode.SpecialCode, FinancialPlanner.LastName) AS [SpecialCode],
           SUM(Asset.Value) AS [HHValue],
           SUM(CASE WHEN FinancialInst.Name = 'National Financial Services' THEN Asset.Value
                    ELSE 0 END) AS [NationalValue],
           SUM(CASE WHEN FinancialInst.Name <> 'National Financial Services' THEN Asset.Value
                    ELSE 0 END) AS [DirectValue]
FROM       PlanFirmSpecCode
INNER JOIN FinPlanSpecCode
        ON PlanFirmSpecCode.PlanFirmSpecCodeID = FinPlanSpecCode.PlanFirmSpecCodeID
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Household
                INNER JOIN Account
                        ON Household.HouseholdID = Account.HouseholdID
                INNER JOIN Asset
                        ON Account.AccountID = Asset.AccountID
                INNER JOIN FinancialPlanner
                        ON Household.FinancialPlannerID = FinancialPlanner.FinancialPlannerID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN FinancialInst
                        ON Account.FinancialInstID = FinancialInst.FinancialInstID
            ON FinPlanSpecCode.FinancialPlannerID = FinancialPlanner.FinancialPlannerID
WHERE      (Account.Closed <> 'Y')
AND        (Asset.Value > '0')
AND        (Account.Managed <> 'N')
GROUP BY   Household.Name,
           FinancialPlanner.LastName,
           COALESCE(PlanFirmSpecCode.SpecialCode, FinancialPlanner.LastName)
ORDER BY   Household.Name;
```